# Python sklearn TfidfVectorizer doesn't work

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying to do TF-IDF with a function as analyzer. This functions returns word ngrams.

My problem comes when I try the fit_transform function, it seems to stop the execution and doesn't do anything. I have no idea why and I didn't found any solution. I am using Anaconda Navigator. The code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
def ngrams(string, n=3):
    string = re.sub(r'[,-./]|\sBD',r'', string)
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]

def main():
    termList = getListofTerms(path)
    print("Start TF-IDF")
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, analyzer=ngrams)
    tf_idf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(termList)
    print("Completed")

if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

The list of terms has 550.000 elements with 1, 2 ,3, 4, or 5 words. The output when I run the code is:

```
In [1]: runfile('test.py', wdir='D:/tests')
Start TD-IDF

In [1]:
```

It never prints the last line of the main function, and it doesn't raise any error, so I am really confused and don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: have you tried running it with just a few elements? i.e. tf_idf_matrix =vectorizer.fit_transform(termList[:500])

Comment: yes, I tried but the result is the same